# Parsing arp.exe - WaitForExit(60000) times out

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to parse arp.exe's output to get the MAC address for a computer. I'm able to parse ping.exe and obtain the IP address but for some reason arp.exe appears to never exit. If I remove the arguments I it exits almost instantly. If I run the command myself in command prompt it outputs the result in less than one second. I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
Public Function DNSLookup(ByVal dnsName As String)

#If Not Debug Then
    Try
#End If
    Dim p As New Process
    With p.StartInfo
        .FileName = "ping.exe"
        .Arguments = "-n 1 -4 " + dnsName 'Send 1 echo/packet (-n 1) and force IPv4 (-4)
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
    End With

    p.Start()
    If p.WaitForExit(5000) Then

        'Find and parse "Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=xx time=xms TTL=xxx"
        Dim result As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd 'Read the result from the command line
        Dim i As Integer = result.IndexOf("Reply from ") + 11 '11 is the length of "Reply from "
        result = result.Substring(i, result.IndexOf(": bytes=") - i) 'Get the IP from the command line output

        Return result
    Else
        Throw New System.Exception("DNS lookup failed. Timeout exceeded")
    End If

#If Not Debug Then
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
#End If

End Function

Public Function GetMACAddress(ByVal dnsName As String)
    Dim ip As String = DNSLookup(dnsName)

#If Not Debug Then
    Try
#End If
    Dim arp As New Process
    With arp.StartInfo
        .FileName = "arp.exe"
        .Arguments = "-a" ' | find " + Chr(34) + ip + Chr(34) 'Example: arp -a | find "192.168.0.1"
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = False
        .UseShellExecute = False
    End With

    arp.Start()
    If arp.WaitForExit(60000) Then
        MsgBox(arp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd)
    Else
        Throw New System.Exception("ARP lookup failed. Timeout exceeded")

    End If

    Return 1 '### TO DO: Return parsed MAC address

#If Not Debug Then
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
#End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this wasn't working with the arguments just set to "-a" last night as when I ran it this morning that worked. However I realised that the reason my full argument wasn't working is because "| find" isn't an argument recognised by arp.exe. To solve it I've used cmd.exe /c arp. Updated code below works:

```
Public Function GetMACAddress(ByVal dnsName As String)
    Dim ip As String = DNSLookup(dnsName)

#If Not Debug Then
    Try
#End If
    Dim arp As New Process
    With arp.StartInfo
        .FileName = "cmd.exe"
        .Arguments = "/c arp -a | find " + Chr(34) + ip + Chr(34) 'Example: arp -a | find "192.168.0.1"
        .CreateNoWindow = False
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = False
        .UseShellExecute = False
    End With

    arp.Start()
    If arp.WaitForExit(5000) Then
        MsgBox(arp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd)
    Else
        Throw New System.Exception("ARP lookup failed. Timeout exceeded")
    End If

    Return 1 '### TO DO: Return parsed IP address

#If Not Debug Then
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
#End If

End Function
```

Comment: um .... in your first example the "find"-part is commented out ... thats why it didnt work. You can even see SO colouring it grey, which immediately leaps to the eye ...

Comment: I commented that out to see if it was causing the problem. But for some unknown reason it still didn't work when just using -a and nothing else. However the next morning when I ran it again without making any changes (still using -a only) it worked... I don't understand why that happened :S putting the "| find" part back then immediately broke it again. Using cmd /c has been working perfectly with the "| find" argument.

Comment: it is best to actually call WINAPI-functions for tasks like these, using commandline-tools and passing parameters always yields unexpected results, thats simply not how one does develop software within windows, that only works on linux

Comment: Thank's for the link. I wanted to use API in the beginning but struggled at first to find any information on it. I actually found that page eventually, unfortunately just before realising you had posted the link for me lol. I'm now using API for ping and arp.

Comment: additionally : dont use Interop if you want to access inaccessible WINAPI-functions, interop is highly error-prone if you dont EXACTLY know what you're doing - which requires deep insight and knowledge. Create a C++/CLR-project in your solution instead - you can safely call your CLR-methods easily from within VB or C#; without all of the interop-overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. But I'm self taught and only code as a hobby. I'm afraid everything you just said went straight over my head lol.

Comment: then how were you able to call WINAPI-functions within VB.NET? Magic?

Comment: I found the following example online: 
    <DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Friend Shared Function SendARP(
                     DestIP As UInt32,
                     SrcIP As UInt32,
                     pMacAddr() As Byte,
                     ByRef PhyAddrLen As Int32) As UInt32
    End Function

Comment: thats interop. Never use interop, despite the fact that a lot of newbies on the internet give examples for it.

Comment: Ok thank you. In that case you said to create a C++/CLR project in my solution. What would I search for to try to find an example? or at least something to get me started? Thanks.

Comment: well thats easy : create a new C++/CLR - project in visual studio, include Iphlpapi.h and start using SendARP directly - you will also need to either link to Iphlpapi.dll or link Iphlpapi.lib statically, both should be available if you installed visual studio. Now : you need to reference your new project in your VB-project aaand thats about it, you will have every public method available, its really easy - just create a new instance of your C++-class and call the methods - your class will have to have the "ref"-keyword in order to be visible from within VB.net, you will also need to import it.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of the advice and information, it's much appreciated. I will have a go at changing my code and see how I get on.